# Redirect www to non-www not working in Traefik 2

Tags: docker, traefik

I sett up Traefik to manage my docker containers but I can redirect www to non-www for my domain. I've tried everything in the forums but no luck

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.node.entrypoints=http"
  - "traefik.http.routers.node.rule=Host(`awebsite.com`) || Host(`www.awebsite.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.vk-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex=^https://www.awebsite.com/(.*)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement=https://awebsite.com/$${1}"

  - "traefik.http.routers.node.middlewares=vk-https-redirect"
  - "traefik.http.routers.node-secure.entrypoints=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.node-secure.rule=Host(`awebsite.com`) || Host(`www.awebsite.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.node-secure.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.node-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
  - "traefik.http.routers.node-secure.service=node"
  - "traefik.http.services.node.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"
  - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
```

Answer (score 9):

It not enough to define the redirect middleware, you also need to use it with the defined routers

here is you middleware definitions

```
 - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.regex=^https://www.awebsite.com/(.*)"
 - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.replacement=https://awebsite.com/$${1}"
```

you may need to add this lable too

```
traefik.http.middlewares.test-redirectregex.redirectregex.permanent=true
```

but you never used it in any of the defined routers. For instance, if you want this to apply to `node-secure` router, you need to add this label

```
- "traefik.http.routers.node-secure.middlewares=test-redirectregex"
```

More information, details, and examples can be found in this [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/traefik-2-1-as-a-reverse-proxy-c9e274da0a32)

Comment: Why do we use this tags? Should I use the same for me? $${1} Thank you.

Comment: `$${1}` will have the value that matches the regex `(.*)` (all chars after the domain name ). I guess you need it unless you only want to redirect the home page only

Comment: Oh my god, `traefik.http.routers.node-secure.middlewares=test-redirectregex` is the freaking keyword I am hunting all the time! Thanks you a lot! Karma poin ts to you!

Comment: FYI: I did several `docker-compose restart`s, but that's not enough. You need to up / down your containers.

Answer (score -1):

```
- "traefik.http.routers.node-secure.middlewares=test-redirectregex"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.